# GA4 BigQuery daily export stopped for unknown reason?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have set up a daily GA4 BigQuery export successfully for several BQ projects. I could see the daily partition tables exported in bigquery.

However, the data export stopped around end of Sept in one of the projects. Other projects seem fine so far. Anybody know what the possible reason for this is? How to fix it?

I didn't receive any notification/alert to tell me the data size exceeded export limit. But I have already setup the billing account.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Go to the left side panel of your BigQuery page and click on "Data Transfers". You're gonna see your scheduled transfer with an error icon. There you can check the error message and which service account Firebase is using.

For more detailed troubleshooting you can go to Cloud Logging and query BigQuery instance errors.

If it is a permission problem, go to "IAM & Admin" and add the required permissions to the service account Firebase is using.
If it is a quota problem, go to "APIs & Services" and check how you are consuming your quotas.

Comment: I had this error and it was caused by permissions issues.
You need to check your logs in Cloud Logging, then search any errors with query filter: 

`resource.type="bigquery_resource" severity=ERROR analytics_xxxxxxx`
replace analytics_xxxxxxx with your ga4 id